Superluminal expansion
It is known that for distances larger than the radius of the Hubble Sphere, according to the Hubbble Law  galaxies are receding with velocities larger tha c. I this a real effect violating the speed limit of objects, or is it more accurate to assume that it is space between sources that is stretching at this speed?

Neither is an appropriate interpretation.
The recession rates associated with Hubble's law are not velocities in the relativistic sense (i.e., angles in spacetime), so there's no reason they should be limited to the speed of light. Notice for example that they are linearly additive, whereas velocities in relativity add nonlinearly according to the relativistic velocity addition formula. Cosmological recession rates are more like rapidity than speed.
Meanwhile, while it is common to attribute these recession speeds to "expanding space", there is absolutely no physics in that description. It's just a coordinate convention. Within the context of established physics, there can be no objective sense in which space expands, contracts, moves, or such.

You’re right that it’s not motion in the regular sense. We can see something recede at lightspeed, or faster than lightspeed, if it’s more than a few megaparsecs away. This is allowed within cosmological law, as per the FLRW metric. The way you show this is by constructing the metric and finding that two points, otherwise stationary, have distance between them that seems to grow at a rate proportional to the distance itself. The objects don’t actually “move”, perse; they occupy the same points in space at all times (ignoring their mutual gravitation and other forces), it’s just the distance between those two points as measured using the spacetime metric goes up over time.
